# using redis-py to bulk populate a redis list

Tags: python, django, redis

In a Django project, I'm using redis as a fast backend.

I can LPUSH multiple values in a redis list like so:

```
lpush(list_name,"1","2","3")
```

However, I can't do it if I try

```
values_list = ["1","2","3"]
lpush(list_name,values_list)
```

For the record, this doesn't return an error. Instead it creates a list `list_name` with a single value. E.g. `['["1","2","3"]']`. This is not usable if later one does `AnObject.objects.filter(id__in=values_list)`. Nor does it work if one does `AnObject.objects.filter(id__in=values_list[0])` (error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[').

What's the best way to LPUSH numerous values in bulk into a redis list (python example is preferred).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lpush (list_name, *values_list)`

This will unpack contents in value_list as parameters.

If you have enormous numbers of values to insert into db, you can pipeline them. Or you can use the command line tool `redis-cli --pipe` to populate a database